# Add option selected to TEXTAREA separate for comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, textarea

Could you help me to lograte this example please:

I have the next elements:

[image]

I need an option selected when you add the textarea and separated by a comma, for example:

Here i select once option:

[image]

Later this option must to add to the TEXTAREA, some like this:

[image]

and in other SELECT when i select other option, happen the same action:

[image]
[image]

and so on, could help, thanks.

The HTML is:

```
    <select id="filter" name="filter">
    <option id="A" value="A">Option1</option>
    <option id="B" value="B">Option2</option>
    <option id="C" value="C">Option3</option>
    <option id="D" value="D">Option4</option>
</select>
<textarea name="key" id="field"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<select id="filter2" name="filter2">
    <option id="A" value="A">Option1</option>
    <option id="B" value="B">Option2</option>
    <option id="C" value="C">Option3</option>
    <option id="D" value="D">Option4</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id="filter3" name="filter3">
    <option id="A" value="A">Option1</option>
    <option id="B" value="B">Option2</option>
    <option id="C" value="C">Option3</option>
    <option id="D" value="D">Option4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you share the html as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $texta = $('#field');
var $selects = $('select');
$selects.change(function () {
    var opts = $selects.find('option:selected').map(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text());
    }).get();
    $texta.val(opts.join())
}).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q4hqX/)

Comment: Your example work fine, and very mych fast, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#filter,#filter2,#filter3").change(function(){
    $("#field").val(
        [$(":selected", "#filter").text(),
         $(":selected", "#filter2").text(),
         $(":selected", "#filter3").text()
        ].join(",")
    );
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/KJL4F/

By the way, there are repeated `id`s in your HTML and that is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a class-name to associate the relevant `select` elements (in this case I've used `class="selectFilters"`), leading to the following jQuery:

```
$('.selectFilters').on('change', function(){
    $('#field').val(function(){
        return $('.selectFilters').map(function(){
            return $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        }).get().join(', ') + '.';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t5yM6/).

If, however, you want to get only those values that have been changed by the user, you could set a property on those elements, initially to `false`, that could track whether they've been modified (called appropriately, in this instance, `modified`):

```
$('.selectFilters').prop('modified', false).on('change', function(){
    this.modified = true;
    $('#field').val(function(){
        return $('.selectFilters').map(function(){
            if (this.modified) {
                return $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            }
        }).get().join(', ');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t5yM6/2/).

And to allow for those instances where a user might open the `select` and then decide the default option is the best choice, I've also used the `blur` functionality (not *instead*, in order to allow the `textarea` to update as soon as the `option` is changed):

```
$('.selectFilters').prop('modified', false).on('change blur', function(){
    this.modified = true;
    $('#field').val(function(){
        return $('.selectFilters').map(function(){
            if (this.modified) {
                return $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            }
        }).get().join(', ');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t5yM6/3/).

Incidentally, you ***must*** avoid duplicate `id` properties in your HTML (an `id` may be used only once in the whole of the document in order to be valid), further, while HTML5 allows for an `id` to start with a numeric character it remains awkward to select those elements in CSS (in the case of `option` elements this isn't a problem since CSS doesn't/can't do much with them; for other elements it's more of an issue).

Also, you're using a lot of HTML to style your content (primarily `<br />` elements); don't: the HTML should show the content, CSS should style it. For example:

```
select, textarea {
    display: block;
    width: 12em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t5yM6/4/).

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: You're very welcome; I'm glad to have been of assistance! Out of curiosity, what approach (if any) did you take?

Comment: sorry for the latest reply within, as the second approach served me too.